# AS3: Function that determines if parameter is int or Number

Tags: actionscript-3, types, parameters

I want to write a function that accepts either an int or a Number as a parameter and does different things depending on what type it is. My first question is what to use in the signature, Object or Number? I was thinking Number because it covers both int and Number.

```
function myFunction(p:Number):void { //Should p be of type Object or Number?
    if (p is int) trace("Parameter is int.");
    else if (p is Number) trace("Parameter is Number.");
}
```

The problem is I want it to be classified as a Number if the parameter has a decimal point like 1.00. That will still come up as int. Does anyone have any ideas how to do that? I suppose I could convert p to a String and then check to see if it contains a decimal point, but I was hoping there was an easier way.

Comment: Use the Number type, Object is costly (since it's a dynamic type).

Comment: Why do you want to distinguish input of `1.00` from `1`? My guess is you should either have two different functions like `myFunctionForInteger(i:int)` and `myFunctionForDecimal(n:Number)`, or additional parameters like `muFunction(n:Number, decimalPrecision:int)`. Otherwise, it's just not going to be clear what the function expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I see is with the following sentence:

> The problem is I want it to be classified as a Number if the parameter has a decimal point like 1.00.

Let's say we have an `int` variable called `x`, and we set it to `1`.  Does it look like `1`, `1.00`, or `1x10^-1`?  The answer is always no.  Even if somebody were to type this:

```
myFunction(1.00);
```

the number still wouldn't actually look like anything.  It's just the number one.  Its only representation basically is however it looks in the actual machine bit representation (either floating point-style or just `000...001`).

All it is is a number - whether stored in a `Number` variable or an `int` variable.  Trying to convert it to a `String` won't help, as the information isn't there to begin with.  The closest you're going to be able to come to this is pretty much going to be to use a `String` as the parameter type and see if somebody calls `myFunction("1")` or `myFunction("1.00")`.

Only do something like this if you really have to, due to the wide range of stuff that could actually be stored in a `String`.  Otherwise your `is` keywords should be the best way to go.  But whichever one you choose, do not use an `Object` or untyped parameter; go with either a `String` or (much more preferably) a `Number`.